# Body is not filling the whole page

Tags: css, document-body

My body no matter how hard I try wont get any bigger than a small line on the top of my page, I've tried just about everything so if someone could help me maybe something is wrong with my css i'm not seeing let me know

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.rw-wrapper {
  width: 80%;
  position: fixed;
  margin: 110px auto 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Cinzel Decorative', cursive;
  padding: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-left: 40px;
  margin-top: 138px;
}

.rw-sentence {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0, 0.8);
}

.rw-sentence span {
  color: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 200%;
  font-weight: normal;
}

.rw-words {
  display: inline;
  text-indent: 10px;
}

.rw-words span {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  color: #F13D19;
}

.rw-words-1 span {
  animation: rotateWordsFirst 18s linear infinite 0s;
}

.rw-words-2 span {
  animation: rotateWordsSecond 18s linear infinite 0s;
}

.rw-words span:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
  color: #11B61B;
}

.rw-words span:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
  color: #2CCBC1;
}

.rw-words span:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 9s;
  color: #7a6b9d;
}

.rw-words span:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 12s;
  color: #E91313;
}

.rw-words span:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: 15s;
  color: white;
}

.rw-hero {
  font-style: bold;
  font-size: 75px;
}

@keyframes rotateWordsFirst {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    height: 0px;
  }
  8% {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 60px;
  }
  19% {
    opacity: 1;
    height: 60px;
  }
  25% {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 60px;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes rotateWordsSecond {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    animation-timing-function: ease-in;
    width: 0px;
  }
  10% {
    opacity: 0.3;
    width: 0px;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 100%;
  }
  27% {
    opacity: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

img {
  position: fixed;
  top: 25px;
  left: 25px;
  min-width: 97.5%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}

.words {
  text-align: left;
  padding-top: 160px;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

#ap {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1860;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 15;
  top: 81.5%;
  left: 9s.5%;
  margin: -100px 0 0 -150px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Neverwinter Beginners Guide</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cinzel+Decorative:700" rel="stylesheet">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/scripts.js"></script>
  <img class="img" src="images/full_drag.png">
</head>

<body id="wrapper">
  <div class="words">
    <section class="rw-wrapper">
      <h2 class="rw-sentence">
        <span>Are you a</span>
        <div class="rw-words rw-words-1">
          <span>Fighter?</span>
          <span>Hunter?</span>
          <span>Paladin?</span>
          <span>Wizard?</span>
          <span>Rogue?</span>
          <span class="rw-hero">Hero?</span>
        </div>
      </h2>
    </section>
  </div>
  gnkrsjl;l
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: For what it's worth your rw-wrapper class sets a position of fixed and takes all your content out of the page flow so it won't expand the body. Also you're setting the body height with overflow hidden so that could cause you problems too. And is there a reason you have an img tag in your document head?

Comment: I tried taking out the fixed position and fixed the body height and overflow issue, still not working. Even if I put elements inside the body it still doesn't change. Also the image is going to be my navigation should I move it out of the head?